# Sitecore IndexFolder (override default setting) not working

Tags: sitecore

I've recently had some trouble moving the location of the indexes folder (for the in built Sitecore Lucene indexes).

I have updated the setting "IndexFolder" (originally in web.config but moved out into include). The config output in http://{mydomain}/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx is correct, the setting has the correct path (now in the Data folder instead of Website folder).

However, when I jump into the control panel and rebuild the index, it is still created in the default location ("/indexes", relative to the web application).

Has anyone had a similar problem in Sitecore not using the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, when adding settings to an include file make sure you get the xml path correct.

I had:

```xml
<sitecore>
    <setting name="IndexFolder" value="C:\...\Indexes" />
</sitecore>
```

Should have had:

```xml
<sitecore>
    <settings>
        <setting name="IndexFolder" value="C:\...\Indexes" />
    </settings>
</sitecore>
```

All is well in Lucene world. Thanks for your help everyone, but it turns out I'm a victim of my own stupidity.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the new folder is writable by ASPNET-user or NETWORK SERVICES.
If that's not working, list a Sitecore support case.